# Is there a way to create an array in java with some initialized numbers and then add random numbers to it

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers

I am trying to create an array with 7 numbers that are manually inputted and 43 that random.

I am able to do it in C but I am facing a challenge in java the 7 numbers that are manually inputted keep coming out as zeros when the array is printed

```
int arr3[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}; // this is where I created the array 
arr3=new int[50];
```

// this is where I tried to populate it

```
for (int i = 7; i < arr5.length; i++) 
{
arr3[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 1500);
}
```

I would like the first few numbers to be manually inputted and the rest to be randomly created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you do `arr3=new int[50];` you reset every value in the list to 0 and set the size of the array to 50. Here `int arr3[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};` you are setting the size to 7. What you could do is this for example :

```java
int arr3[]= new int[50];
arr3[0] = 1;
arr3[1] = 2;
arr3[2] = 3;
arr3[3] = 4;
arr3[4] = 5;
arr3[5] = 6;
arr3[6] = 7;

for (int i = 7; i < arr3.length; i++) {
    arr3[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 1500);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This statement:

```
arr3 = new int[50];
```

Is re-declaring `arr3`, meaning that anything that `arr3` was initialized with is discarded, and that's why you see the default `int` value (`0`).

You can solve it by copying the `input` into the larger array:

```
int[] arr3 = new int[50];
int[] input = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    arr3[i] = input[i];
}

for (int i = input.length; i < arr3.length; i++) {
    arr3[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 1500);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are creating a new, empty, array that is replacing the first.

```
 int arr3[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}; // new int[7]; populated with the values
 arr3 = new int[50]; // new, empty, array and replacing the first
```

I recommend using `System.arraycopy` to copy values into your array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create the array
    int[] array = new int[50];

    // copy initial values into the array
    int[] values = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    System.arraycopy(values, 0, array, 0, values.length);

    // populate random values
    for (int i = values.length; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 1500);
    }

    // print the array
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost getting it right. What you should do is -

```
int arr3[] = new int[50]; //creating a new array
int arr3[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
```

What you were doing wrong was that you were creating an array `arr3` of size `7` and then re-creating it with size `50` so in the memory when you create the new array with size `50` the previous value were getting replaced by `0` as in java every element of array is by default initialized with `0`.

Now you can populate it easily. Also I would recommend to use `Java.util.Random` class for generating random numbers. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have all answered your question directly (and well), so I would like to suggest another approach instead.

You don't appear to have any need for the specific array length (it isn't directly used in the second loop) so may find it easier to use a List then convert it to an array when you finish.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=1; i<=7; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}

for (int i = 7; i < arr5.length; i++) {
    list.add((int) (Math.random() * 1500));
}

int[] arr3 = list.toArray(new int[list.size()]);
```